# How can I use resources in forms with type arguments?

Tags: .net, winforms, generics, embedded-resource

I've added a type argument to my form by adding it to both `Form1.cs` and `Form1.Designer.cs`:

```
partial class Form1<T> { ... }
```

This works until I add any resources to my form, like an icon. When I do, this line gets added:

```
ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
```

If I change this to say `typeof(Form1<T>)` it compiles but at runtime I get

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   `"My.Assembly.Form1'1.resources"` was correctly embedded or linked
>   into assembly `"My.Assembly`" at compile time, or that all the
>   satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Trying `typeof(Form1<T>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()` also fails. How can I use a generic form's resources?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix embedded resources for a generic UserControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627431/fix-embedded-resources-for-a-generic-usercontrol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a issue raised here - 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115397/component-resource-manager-doesnt-work-with-generic-form-classes

But, **SO has a solution** to this. See here -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1627605/763026

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find that existing solution, but it works for forms as well as UserControls.